# Many-to-Many Relationships in Realm using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, many-to-many, realm, rlmarray, rlmlinkingobjects

I have spent hours upon hours trying to figure out how to setup the models for object relationships and create/delete many-to-many relationships in Realm using Objective-C. The documentation has been less than helpful. I could use some guidance on whether to use RLMArray or RLMLinkingObjects... If I use RLMLinkingObjects to set up my to-many relationships, I cannot use `addObject:` to create the relationships, and I cannot find any way to delete a relationship. I am moving from a Core Data relational database and have several many-to-many relationships that I am trying to model, and this just makes no sense at all to me. The only documentation showing a many-to-many relationship shows a class relating two of its own properties. One of the properties uses RLMArray and the other uses RLMLinkingObjects. This makes no sense to me, since a many-to-many relationship is supposed to be bi-directional, and relationships should be able to be added or deleted via either side. Maybe I am thinking about this wrongly, but I am lost and would appreciate some help.

Comment: `RLMArray` is a unidirectional link to multiple objects, and `RLMLinkingObjects` is a unidirectional inverse link to the objects that are linking to the object. The relationship can be modified via the `RLMArray`, which will automatically manage its inverse relation (corresponding `RLMLinkingObjects`). If you need to modify the relationship from the target, then you can find the object with the `RLMArray` using a link query across the linking objects via primary key.

Comment: At this point, could you possibly direct me to some code that demonstrates this? I am not trying to get someone to do my work for me - I truly have spent hours and researched it as thoroughly as I possibly can and do not understand how to set this all up.

Comment: ...well, I'll try to put some snippets together from the docs. I'm not well-versed in anything iOS (especially if you see my post history and tags)

Comment: I do appreciate it - but I've scoured the docs and this still doesn't make any sense to me. I guess I am just not grasping it.

Comment: For a to-many, do we just randomly assign one end of the relationship as RLMArray and the other as RLMLinkingObjects?

Comment: And even for a one-to-many, do we assign the list as RLMArray or RLMLinkingObjects? It seems there is a choice to be made, and it's just not clear how to go about making it.

Comment: Well pretty much, depending on which side points towards which side. The inverse is auto-managed. For example, you could model `dogs.owner` as the RLMArray, but you could also model `person.dogs` as such. And generally, `person.dogs` makes more sense. `RLMArray` is where you add what belongs to the object, and the linking ones are automatically managed if you add/remove anything to RLMArray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146586/discussion-between-sahm-and-epicpandaforce).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Many` relationships in Realm are modelled with `RLMArray`. Every to-one and to-many relationship however creates its own corresponding inverse relationship, which is modelled by `RLMLinkingObjects` (the objects that are linking to this current object).

So `RLMArray` is a unidirectional link to multiple objects, and `RLMLinkingObjects` is a unidirectional inverse link to the objects that are linking to the object. The relationship can be modified via the `RLMArray`, which will automatically manage its inverse relation (corresponding `RLMLinkingObjects`).

If you need to modify the relationship from the target, then you can find the object with the `RLMArray` using a link query across the linking objects via primary key.

```
import <Realm/Realm.h>

@class Person;

// Dog model
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSInteger id;
@property NSString *name;
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *owners;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Dog) // define RLMArray<Dog>

// Person model
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSInteger            id;
@property NSString             *name;
@property NSDate               *birthdate;
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person) // define RLMArray<Person>

// Implementations
@implementation Dog
+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{
        @"owners": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:Person.class propertyName:@"dogs"],
    };
}

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}

+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties {
  return @[@"name"];
}
@end

@implementation Person
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}

+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties {
  return @[@"name"];
}
@end
```

So when you modify `person.dogs` in a transaction, then `dog.owners` will be automatically updated.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    Person *jim = [[Person objectsWhere:@"name == 'Jim'"] firstObject];
    // Jim is owner of Rex 
    Dog * rex = [[Dog objectsWhere:@"name == 'Rex'"] firstObject];
    [jim.dogs addObject:rex]; // <-- now rex's `owners` contains `jim`
}];
```

You can read more about relationships in Realm [**here**](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#relationships).

Comment: Can a dog have multiple owners in your example? Is this a many-to-many relationship you are modeling?

Comment: A person can have multiple dogs. Afterwards the dog doesn't really care whether it's one or many that's pointing to it, it's always modelled as linking objects which is 0..*

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if this is how I model a many-to-many. So, if a dog can have multiple owners, that would help me understand.

Comment: `RLMLinkingObjects` is a list, so technically yes, in this model, a Dog can have multiple owners. It does **not** restrict it to 1 owner, that is for certain.

Comment: So then this is the preferred way to model a many-to-many? If so, what would you change about it to model a many-to-one? For example, what would the code look like if a dog could only have one owner, but an owner could have multiple dogs?

Comment: Then the **Dog** would need to specify `Person *owner;` (NOT array because you said *one*), and then **Person** would have the `RLMLinkingObjects*` field called `dogs`.

Comment: So the person would have RLMLinkingObjects for dogs and not RLMArray for dogs? Is this always the case?

Comment: Oh, I thought it had to have one or the other, RLMArray or RLMLinkingObjects

Comment: `RLMArray*` models MANY links. `SomeObject*` models ONE links. `RLMLinkingObjects*` models INVERSE links.

Comment: I get that (to some, limited extent, as you can see), but if I use Person *owner; on Dog, I can use only RLMArray or RLMLinkingObjects for dogs on Person - am I wrong? I am truly not trying to be obtuse (it just comes naturally).

Comment: Actually, then you can only use `RLMLinkingObjects*` for `dogs` field in `Person`, because it is the *inverse* link for `owner`. Well technically you *can* manage multiple links side-by-side, but it makes *your* life more complicated to have two links instead of one where the other direction is auto-managed. But this is all in the docs I linked at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: But is this the case for every one-to-many inverse relationship? RLMLinkingObjects as opposed to RLMArray? I have read the docs, they just left me with many questions.

Comment: Every inverse relationship is modeled with `RLMLinkingObjects*`, yes. Because they are "the objects that are linking to this current object".

Comment: Okay, I will use Class name/RLMLinkingObjects for one-to-many inverse relationships, and RLMArray/RLMLinkingObjects for many-to-many inverse relationships.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. So much.